# C++, strftime to string

Tags: c++

I make such function to get required time info in string form.

```
string gettimeinfo()
{
    tm * timeinfo;
    time_t rawtime;
    char timebuff[120] = {0};
    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);
    strftime(timebuff, 120, "%d.%m.%Y. %H:%M:%S %x %W %I:%M %p %a %b %A %B %Z\n", timeinfo);
    return string(timebuff);
}
```

This compiles without error and works as expected.
But when debugging on code:blocks/GCC program stops at return statement and debug warning appear:

```
In std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) () ()
```

What happens and how to get rid of this?

EDIT: Whole error is:

```
In std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () ()
#1  0x004013fe in gettimeinfo () at C:\programi\[connectcpp\general.cpp:36
C:\programi\[connectcpp\general.cpp:36:785:beg:0x4013fe
At C:\programi\[connectcpp\general.cpp:36
In char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) () ()
In std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () ()
In operator new(unsigned int) () ()
```

Comment: Is the buffer large enough? You should check that `strftime` returns a size, not zero.

Comment: And is that the whole warning? Usually, they give useful information, not just a function name.

Comment: I updated question with whole warning. Yes, buffer is long enoough to hold whole info.

Comment: Nope, you're still missing part of the warning.

Comment: It compiles fine on Visual studio..

Comment: @Alien01: Indeed, this is some kind of run-time error. But we don't know what, since the useful part of the warning is still missing.

Comment: But for me I did not get any runtime error either..I included ctime and string and it worked fine

Comment: This is whole warning. Ihave included time.h but with ctime same happens. I can compile this with GCC also but when debugging step-by-step in conversion from timebuff to string those errors appears and debugger won't step out from function.

Comment: With g++ 4.7.3, gdb 7.4.1 no problem in running your code. I just added `#include<string>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;`
on top and `int main() {
        cout << "time is " << gettimeinfo() << "!!!\n";
}`
on bottom.

Comment: @Alien01: Unfortunately, "works on my machine" doesn't help the OP. But you're right that this code seems to be correct, and the problem is probably somewhere else (perhaps earlier stack corruption, which is a big danger with this kind of error-prone C-style malarkey).

Comment: Mike, how would you get such string withut using of C style functions without boost and to be portable?

Comment: @user973238: You probably can't do it any other way if you can't use Boost for some weird reason; I'm just saying that doing this kind of thing is likely to cause stack corruption and other memory issues if you're not very careful; for example, if you forget to check return values.

Comment: @user973238: As for the warning: are you running it directly in a debugger, or through an IDE? You're definitely missing the useful part of the warning, as no debugger simply gives you a stack dump with no explanation. I'd try running the code under Valgrind, if you're using Linux.

Comment: Why I can't use boost? I dont want to use it. I am debugging through IDE. But all people here look's to wrong thing. Problem isn't in time, problem is in string conversion. It is possible that I have some error earlier but I don't know for that.

Comment: @user973238: I'm not trying to start an argument about whether to use Boost; I'm just saying that C-style memory manipulation is error-prone, so if you're doing it a lot (and not checking return values) then you may well have stack corruption from some earlier operation. But since you still haven't told us what the error message says, and there appears to be nothing wrong with the posted code (although it really should check the return value), there's little we can do. Try running the code under Valgrind if possible; although unfortunately that often doesn't help much with stack problems.

Comment: @user973238: Sorry, I just noticed that you're using Windows, so Valgrind won't help.

Comment: Ok Mike, I will switch to linux and see what happens here. As I can see on SO there are many people which throws in exactly that when assigning value to a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you should *at least* check the return value from `strftime`. If it returns zero, your buffer is invalid and you shouldn't try constructing a string from it.

Secondly, an error in `new` often means your heap was damaged *before* this operation. If you stick a

```
std::string tmp("heap test");
```

before your return statement for example, and that fails in the same way, you definitely have some prior damage (sadly the converse is not true, since these things often aren't deterministic). Using valgrind or some other heap checker is a better bet.

Comment: This function is first call in main function. If I put string tmp you suggest before calling this function then everything is OK. Then I set string tmp as a first line in a function and there don't pass. Any idea?

Comment: Apart from using a heap checker? If you post the minimal `main` that still reproduces this, it might help ... if you're really doing nothing else, look at removing static/global initializations.

Comment: I need some global variables. But if I look now to all of this, if compiles well, if runs well that may be some quirk in debugger or I broke a standard somewhere. I think, no worth to try to solve it "at any price". If problems will advance then I will keep this function on the eye.

Comment: This is definitely caused with debugger setting "watch scripts" which they turns to ON!! By uncheck that checkbox everything work as expected.